# Returning Integer Array List from another class returns null pointer exceptions when getting specific value

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

new to java and need some pointers

I am trying to create an array list in one class then return it and iterate through its values in a separate main class. However when i use the get method to return a specific value in the array it produce a null pointer exception. What am I doing Wrong ?

```
import java.util.*
public class ReadFile 
{
 
    private ArrayList<Integer> height;

    public ReadFile()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
        {
            height.add(x);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getHeights()
    {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
import java.util.*
    
public class Jumper
{

    private ReadFile readFile;

    public Jumper()
    {
        readFile = new ReadFile();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Jumper game = new Jumper();
        System.out.println(game.readFile.getHeights().get(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a field named `height`:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> height;
```

and then you're déclaring a local variable also named `height`:

```
public ReadFile()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

everything you do with `height` in the constructor is done on the local variable, and nothing is done on the field.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem

`ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Instead of assigning a value to the `height` member field, you create a new `height` variable that only exists inside the constructor.

You should instead do `height = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, similar to how you do with `readFile`.

P.S: Having a local variable with the same name as a member field is called "variable shadowing". Depending on what IDE you are using, it might warn you about it, as it's not an uncommon mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line `ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();` to `height = new ArrayList<Integer>();` inside the constructor of `ReadFile`. What happens is both the `height` references are different.

In this code

```
public ReadFile() {

    ArrayList<Integer> height = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
        height.add(x);
    }
}
```

The `height` is local to the Constructor `ReadFile()`, so only that is initialized and the `private ArrayList<Integer> height;` remains null and that's what causes the Exception.